# Ionic 2's bundle size too large

Tags: performance, angular, ionic2, size, bundle

The final bundle size of my web app after `npm run ionic:build --prod` is near 9 MB.

It makes the app to slow to download. How could I reduze the size of my final bundle?

Comment: for release version try `ionic build --prod --release`

Comment: Wait 9 MB is slow to download ?

Comment: For 3G networks, which are common in Brazil, it is.

Comment: Even in WiFi the app take too many time to load, while some other PWA apps are faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here are definitely a few routes you should take:

1. Uninstall all packages not listed in `package.json`.

   `npm prune`

   You can also add the `--production` flag to remove your devDependencies before production (which is a good idea since you are producing your project.
2. Use code and image minifying tools:

   [Minifier](http://www.minifier.org/)

   [Tiny Png](http://tinypng.com)
3. Manually `Find and Remove` unused image files and code snippets using plain 'ol `Ctrl+Shift+F` or `Cmd+Shift+F`.

Ideally, you should never repeat code and delete unused files. Ionic packages are large, and there is often no way around trimming them without getting rid of important dependencies. Hope this helps.

---

Reference:
[How to reduce Ionic app size!](https://medium.com/@b.sandesh/how-to-reduce-ionic-app-size-b0dd71ae3cd5)